# Excel VBA: Update the formatting for all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I read through a few online tutorials, and use the macro record to learn how to set formats. But I am wondering is there a way to do the following, without using .Select? Or what is the preferred way by programmers?

Requirement for the simple macro:

1. Loop through all the worksheets (visible only)
2. Set bold format to the top row, and set the background to grey
3. Reset the selection to A1 position

()

```
Sub SetAllTopRowBold()
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible Then
        ws.Activate
        Rows(1).Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(190, 190, 190)
        Range("A1").Select
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly against the range object:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible Then
        ws.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        ws.Rows(1).Interior.Color = RGB(190, 190, 190)
        ws.Select
        ws.Range("A1").Select
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: What about if the selection of the worksheet is not A1? As the previous coworker sometimes worked and saved their last position.

Comment: In my haste, I didn't see that part.  In that case, I think your current approach is actually the way to go, except add `ws.` since you're not actually switching sheets within the code:  `ws.Range("A1").Select`.  I added that to my answer.

Comment: I think that is what I need! Thanks Hambone!